# Labels properties changing in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have written this code to change colour of different labels through different buttons
 I am new to app development, just got stuck up in pretty basics:

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn=sender;

    if(btn.tag==1)
    {
        lbl1.text=@"";
        lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }
    if(btn.tag==2)
    {
        lbl2.text=@"";
        lbl2.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else if(btn.tag==3)
    {
        lbl3.text=@"";
        lbl3.backgroundColor=[UIColor magentaColor];
    }
    else if(btn.tag==4)
    {
        lbl4.text=@"";
        lbl4.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else if(btn.tag==5)
    {
        lbl5.text=@"";
        lbl5.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
    }
}
```

After writing the code the colour of label one is only getting changed.
    I have connected all the elements through storyboard though

Comment: Are you sure that all buttons points to the same method for touch event? tags are set as method expects?

Comment: Use breakpoints to check if all buttons call the buttonPressed event, use console to make sure your if() works as expected and buttons have proper tags or at least NSLog tags in this function to see if that works as you expect

Comment: Smells like a case for a switch case

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski  you were right actually,you hit the the right thing all the buttons were not actually calling the ButtonPressed event i cross checked but also due to some reason using sender tag method was also useful ,Thanks fir your help :)

Comment: No problem, glad that I helped. Learning how to debug is first step for better learning curve :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
    {
        NSInteger i = [sender tag];

        if(i==1)
        {
            lbl1.text=@"";
            lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            lbl2.text=@"";
            lbl2.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if(i==3)
        {
            lbl3.text=@"";
            lbl3.backgroundColor=[UIColor magentaColor];
        }
        else if(i==4)
        {
            lbl4.text=@"";
            lbl4.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        }
        else if(i==5)
        {
            lbl5.text=@"";
            lbl5.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
        }
    }
```

Or Simply

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
    {
        if([sender tag]==1)
        {
            lbl1.text=@"";
            lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        }
        if([sender tag]==2)
        {
            lbl2.text=@"";
            lbl2.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if([sender tag]==3)
        {
            lbl3.text=@"";
            lbl3.backgroundColor=[UIColor magentaColor];
        }
        else if([sender tag]==4)
        {
            lbl4.text=@"";
            lbl4.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        }
        else if([sender tag]==5)
        {
            lbl5.text=@"";
            lbl5.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
        }
    }
```

Also check the tags of the buttons.

Comment: Welcome, whenever an answer will help you resolving the issue, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Only replace this line UIButton *btn=sender;

with UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;